# Python str.format, Why don't both of these method do the same thing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I can't understand why the first code snipped doesn't work, It is the same thing as the second one.

(I am working through a book and I don't get why my code doesn't work)

```
# My Code Snippet

x = float(13424)

formatr = "10.4f"

stringToBeFormatted = "<td align='right'>{0:formatr}</td>".format(x)

print(stringToBeFormatted)



# Book's Code Snippet


x = float(13424)

formatr = "10.4f"

stringToBeFormatted = "<td align='right'>{{0:{0}}}</td>".format(formatr)

print(stringToBeFormatted.format(x))



#output should be:

<td align='right'>13434.0000</td>
```

My Code gives an error.  Why don't both code snippets work the same way? I don't see how they differ.

Book's code just inputs the `formatr` inside the `str.format` by the field argument,
and I just input it directly.

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the second example `{{0:{0}}}` has `{0}` in place of the format spec, so the first time it is formatted the spec is put into place and a layer of `{}` is removed from the format mark with double `{{}}`:

```
>>> "{{0:{0}}}".format(formatr)
'{0:10.4f}'
```

then the second time the the field is put into place:

```
>>> '{0:10.4f}'.format(x)
'13424.0000'
```

To do the formatting in one go you need to specify the spec as `{formatr}` and add that as an argument to `.format()`:

```
>>> "{0:{formatr}}".format(x,formatr=formatr)
'13424.0000'
```

or specified as a positional argument:

```
>>> "{0:{1}}".format(x,formatr)
'13424.0000'
```

Comment: Thanks Tadhg, but shouldn't my code work still? The formatr variable stores the format spec "10.4f", and uses that directly in the .format method. It's basically writing "{0:10.4f}".format(x) as you wrote in your second snippet.

Comment: the variable is never used at all, just it's variable name in the string itself! you could do `.replace("formatr",formatr)` to replace all occurrences of the _string_ `formatr` with the _variable_ `formatr` or do `...{0:"+formatr+"}..."` to directly insert the contents of the _variable_ into the string but specifying it as a format variable is definitely the best way to go.

Comment: Tadhg, I get it, finally. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In your example, the python interpreter can't identify 
`formatr` inside `stringToBeFormatted` as a variable and therefore can't resolve it. It would work if you put the `formatr` string (its content) into the `stringToBeFormatted` as is:

```
x = float(13424)

stringToBeFormatted = "<td align='right'>{0:10.4f}</td>".format(x)

print(stringToBeFormatted.format(x))
```

Comment: You have simply hard coded in the value instead of formatting in the spec like the example from the book is doing.